# Why I couldn't set cookies with Node.js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

Here's my code:

```html
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/pinfo", (req, res) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields) {

        var nhs_num = 1000000; // it should be a return value from another function using fields values as parameters

        res.cookie("nhsnum", nhs_num, {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5),
            httpOnly: true
        }); // set a cookie expired in 5 minutes
        console.log(req.cookies.nhsnum);
    })
});
```

The code is in a Node.js server, and it gets form submission from the HTML client, then uses the form details to get a result and finally saves it into the cookie.

When I try to log the cookie, there is an undefined in the console. And I don't understand why. Is there any process that I did wrong?
I really appreciate it if there is someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: Why would there be a cookie in the request that came before you set the cookie for response?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes I noticed that and tried to read the cookie in the next request from the same client, but there was also an undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`req.cookies` contains the cookies that arrived with this incoming request.  It does not contain the cookies that will be set on the response and sent back to the client.

So, when you do `res.cookie(...)` that is adding a cookie to the response object (technically adding a `set-cookie` [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) to the response) so the client will pick up that cookie when it gets the response.

If you want to see the cookie in `req.cookies`, then look at `req.cookies` on the next request from that client (before the cookie expires).  Your newly created cookie should then show on that next request.

In this request, you can see the outgoing cookies by doing this:

```
console.log(res.getHeaders());
```

And, you will see your `nhsnum` cookie like this:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'set-cookie': 'nhsnum=1; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 03 Oct 2022 00:08:01 GMT; HttpOnly'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to log the cookie in req.cookies on the next request from that client, but there is still only the undefined. When I log res.getHeaders(), there is only "  'x-powered-by': 'Express'". I'm considering if it is because I'm running the server in VS2019. Will that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Is your client the same source as the server？if not，you should at client page setting request mode，`credentials: "include",`